# Minted cross reference line

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, minted

I used to use `listings` a lot but `minted+pygmentize` has outstanding output. However, there are a few features from `listings` that are hard to find in `minted`, like having the line numbers on the right.

Is there a way to cross reference lines in a `minted` environment as in `listings`?

Comment: `minted` uses `fancyvrb`, so the documentation of `fancyvrb` will help you.+

Comment: You can use `texcl=true` to allow LaTeX in comments, and then put a `\label` in a comment and `\ref` that.  Unfortunately, Pygments doesn't allow LaTeX anywhere except for comments (though that feature has been [requested](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issue/493/optionally-enable-escaping-to-latex)).  So Pygments is a bit more limited than `listings` in that respect.  (You could always take the direct output of pygmentize and add `\label`'s by hand, but that's probably not what you were looking for.)

Comment: Ok, I added a bogus comment by hand and used the texcl feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is an "ancient" question but I would like to answer it to help those who get here like me. :)

`minted` nows provides a macro called `escapeinside` (also `texcl` and `texcomments` for LaTeX in comments, please check the document for more):

> escapeinside (string) (default: ⟨none ⟩)
>
> Escape to LaTeX between the two characters specified in (string). All code between the two characters will be interpreted as LaTeX and typeset accordingly. This allows for additional formatting. The escape characters need not be identical. Special LaTeX characters must be escaped when they are used as the escape characters (for example, `escapeinside=\#\%`). Requires Pygments 2.0+.
>
> Escaping does not work inside strings and comments (for comments, there is `texcomments`)....

An example given in the document is:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
def f(x):
    y = x|\colorbox{green}{**}|2
return y
\end{minted}
```

I've tried that. We can also use `\label{refname}` to create a line reference using `esacpeinside` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,linenos,gobble=0]{c}
void hello() |\label{line:hello_start}|
{
    printf("Hello minted!\n");
} |\label{line:hello_end}|
int main()
{
    hello(); |\label{line:invoke}|
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
The code at Line~\ref{line:invoke} invokes a function defined
between Line~\ref{line:hello_start} and Line~\ref{line:hello_end}.
\end{document}
```

The example on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zmgksnkdyrgh).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you @mkdong for updating this. I now have a lot of stuff with `listings` but for new projects, I'll think about it.

Comment: I think this only works when the document is not compiled in draft mode (so do not worry about undefined labels in draft mode).

Comment: I spent way too long trying to figure this out. Dashes are _NOT_ allowed in these labels. For some reason, this causes the label to be undefiend. Sucks, because the rest of my document standardized on kebab-casing our refs.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! Seems to be incompatible with `cleveref`, though?

Comment: Also, even after switching from `\cref` to just `\ref`, when I click the reference in the PDF, it jumps to the beginning of the section and does not actually jump to the line number; is there any way to fix this?