# Can you reference lines from source code when using `\inputminted`?

Tags: listings, labels, minted

I wanted to know if there were any methods that would allow me to reference lines in source code that was imported with the `\inputminted` macro from the `minted` package?

My assumption is that this is not possible given that it is an external file?

I am trying to avoid copying the contents of the file manually as I don't want to accidentally forget to update the code in my `.tex` file. So if anyone has any suggestions, I would love to hear them!

Thanks.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{
    linenos
}

\begin{document}
% Report contents
In \hyperref[code.m:30]{Line 30} we can find \dots

% Appendix
\inputminted{MATLAB}{code.m}
% The following LaTeX code is only for illustration purposes
\label{code.m:30}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `\label` in the input file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.m}
Line
Line
Line
Line |\phantomsection\label{thisline}|
Line
Line
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

In \hyperref[thisline]{Line~\ref*{thisline}} we can find \dots

\clearpage

\inputminted[linenos,escapeinside=||]{MATLAB}{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you plan to use `-` in labels, or maybe other characters that may get wrongly interpreted by `minted`, you can use a workaround.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.m}
Line
Line
Line
Line |\mintedlabel{this-line}|
Line
Line
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mintedlabel}[1]{\phantomsection\label{\detokenize{#1}}}

\begin{document}

In \hyperref[this-line]{Line~\ref*{this-line}} we can find \dots

\clearpage

\inputminted[linenos,escapeinside=||]{MATLAB}{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a great method! I didn't think you could overwrite files within LaTeX like that, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Good solution! I found another similar solutions like this (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348665/274163) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410667/274163)). But all solutions (included this) don't work if [I use a `-` inside label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100911/minted-cross-reference-line/348665#comment1476896_348665) (e.g. `\label{this-line}`). In particular I get `! Missing \endcsname inserted.` and `LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference \`this-line' on page 1 undefined on input line 17`.

Comment: @LorenzoFerron I added a workaround.